# Inserting one or more Video s inside a video

Tags: ffmpeg, android

I have a Video lets say LargeVideo.mp4 and I have 2 other small videos as SmallVideo_1.mp4 and SmallVideo_2.mp4. I want to insert the full SmallVideo_1.mp4 and SmallVideo_2.mp4  at 10th sec and 40th sec of LargeVideo respectively.

I'm using

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -fflags +genpts output.mp4
```

contact.txt is

```
file 'LargeVideo.mp4'
inpoint 0.0
outpoint 10
file 'SmallVideo_1.mp4'
inpoint 0
file 'LargeVideo.mp4'
inpoint 10
outpoint 40
file 'SmallVideo_2.mp4'
inpoint 0
file 'LargeVideo.mp4'
inpoint 40
```

The above code works perfectly fine in Windows, But I want to implement this in Android I have added `-safe 0` also in android command but still it is not working

Android is as follows with the same contact.txt

```
String[] cmdConcatVideo = new String[]{"-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", inpCmdFile, "-c:v", "libx264", "-crf", "23", "-fflags", "+genpts", outVideo};
```

I don't know what I'm missing, Any help would be thankful.

--In android It is not failing it works but I'm not getting the desired output. The SmallVideos are not present in the output.

Comment: Share full log of failed command.